# In statistics, is an uppercase x-bar used as a notation for something?

Tags: statistics

I was reading someone's answer and I came across him using the uppercase x-bar as a notation:

"Technically, the standard error is the standard deviation of an estimator. Most commonly, this refers to sample mean $\bar X$ as an estimator of the population mean .

So the 'standard error of the mean' is ($\bar X$)=/√. If  is unknown, it is estimated as the sample standard deviation . This means that the '(estimated) standard error' is /$\sqrt 2$."

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161510/what-is-the-difference-between-bar-x-and-bar-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sample is $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, then $\overline{X} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Sometimes lowercase $x$ is used in place of $X$. See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance) for more detail.